# How can I add +1 to regex capture?

Tags: typescript

I have several strings `text <n>`. I try to do a string replace to get `text <n+1>`. How/is that possible with one RegEx replace?

Consider the following example:

```
const x = 'text 1';
const y1 = x.replace( /text (%d)/, `other text ${'$1' + 1}` );          // y1 = 'other text 11'
const y2 = x.replace( /text (%d)/, `other text ${+'$1' + 1}` );         // y2 = 'other text NaN'
const y3 = x.replace( /text (%d)/, `other text ${Number('$1') + 1}` );  // y3 = 'other text NaN'

const z = x.replace( /text (%d)/, `other text ${......}` );  // How do I get z = 'other text 2' ???
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[You can pass a function instead of a string to replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

```js
const x = 'text 1';
const y = x.replace( /text (\d+)/, function() {
  return 'other text ' + (parseInt(arguments[1]) + 1)
});
console.log(y)
```

Comment: Excellent, that works! Already tried it with a lambda, but then `arguments` seems to be the arguments of the outer function and I didn't get the captured value...